# Can you pass a TJSONObject in REST Debugger

Tags: rest, delphi

No authentication is required to call this REST service that was created with Delphi.
The client Classes API documented (ClientClassesUnit1.pas).

```
    function TGeneralClient.UpdateCIM2(PostData : TJSONOjbect; const ARequestFilter:string):string
    begin
      if FUpdateCIM2Command = nil then
      begin 
        FUpdateCIM2Command := FConnection.CreateCommand;
        FUpdateCIM2Command.RequestType := 'POST';
        FUpdateCIM2Command.Text := 'TGeneral."UpdateCIM2"';
        FUpdateCIM2Command.Prepare(TGeneral_UpdteCIM2);
      end;
      FUpdateCIM2Command.Parameters[0].Value.SetJSONValue(PostData,FInstanceOwner);
      FUpdateCIM2Command.Execute(ARequestFilter);
      Result := FUpdateCIM2Command.Parmeters[1].Value.GetWideString;
    end;
```

But I would like to create a test using the Delphi REST Debugger and I cannot determine what the settings in the utility should be ... or even if the REST Debugger is capable of doing it. Postman tool doesn't seem to work either.

I tried to post a picture but can't because of company policy restrictions.

Method: `POST`

URL: `https://wxdf0-servername.com/snap4.dll/datasnap/rest/TGeneral/UpdatCIM2`

Content type: `application/json`

Custom body  (edited)

```
         {
           "data" :{
              "Stage" :"7",
                 "Step" :"1"
          }
        }
```

All I get in return on the debugger is "500 :Internal Server error"

**What is the proper setup (if possible) to make a call to a Delphi REST call that uses TJSONObject as a parameter?**

Comment: Content type :     application/json

Comment: If even Postman is failing to work, then you are likely just not sending what the REST server is actually expecting.

Comment: I wrote the server side; and if there is a data problem it sends back the exception message; the function returns a string.
It has something to do with the POST function vs. a GET function
There is no examples of POST and REST Debugger usage.
All seem to be GET calls

Comment: Please show your server code. If you can't even get Postman working, how do you expect to get your Delphi code working?

Comment: I don't have a problem with Delphi code; it has been working for years with 300k clients.
 I am trying to get "REST Debugger" or Postman to work with TJSONObject so I can use one of them as a test harness outside of Delphi code.

Answer (score 1):

An object in JSON is surround by `{ }` which you have omitted. As well, properties are separated by a comma.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "Stage": "7",
    "Step": "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: added commas and brackets but still errors